# Is php's json_encode() vulnerable when embedded in a script element?

Tags: javascript, php, xss, json

I had read [OWASP's XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.233_-_JavaScript_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_JavaScript_Data_Values) a long time ago and made a wrapper function to include `JSON_HEX_TAG|JSON_HEX_APOS|JSON_HEX_QUOT|JSON_HEX_AMP` by default so I would be safe. Or so I thought until a user at Freenode/##php told me that was unsafe. OWASP was apparently saying to put JSON into an element, have javascript grab it's contents, and parse it.

This is the worst I could come up with and json_encode() still made it safe. Can anyone think of a string that could break through?

```
Source:
<script>//<![CDATA[
    window.data=<?php echo json_encode(
        "]]>\"'</script><script>alert(document.cookie)</script>"
        ,JSON_HEX_TAG|JSON_HEX_APOS|JSON_HEX_QUOT|JSON_HEX_AMP
    );?>;
//]]></script>

Output:
<script>//<![CDATA[
    window.data="]]\u003E\u0022\u0027\u003C\/script\u003E\u003Cscript\u003Ealert(document.cookie)\u003C\/script\u003E";
/*]]></script>
```

Comment: I don't have a specific vulnerability to report. But, I'd be wary of attempting to find a prefect, universal output encoding scheme. Software and requirements change. You have to look at the context of untrusted data, and modulate your strategy accordingly. It's always simpler to look at whitelisting untrusted data, rather than trying a blind catch all against any known attack. Circumstances vary though, you have to figure out the right approach based on the risks present for each project you push.

Comment: It's not like I'm trying to figure out how to escape text so it can be used in html, javascript, css, and sql, that would be impossible to do because they all have different ways of escaping characters. Attempting to create a universal escaper is how you end up with random html escapes and backslashes in the comments section of some blog no one has ever heard of. The escape function already exists, thus it is far easier to just escape and show a bunch of inert text than to build a function to determine what is safe. Maybe I'm just misinterpreting this nearly two year old comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best solution to this would be to make sure that your servers PHP is up to date. i like to use 5.5.21 as its the latest full release, any above it are available but not properly "released". If you're worried about any possible exploits, read through [php.net](http://www.php.net)'s latest news and search through some of the specific CVE's that they mention. Those are references to exploits that have been patched.